# set on less than error - MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

Ok, So I'm familiar with x86 Microsoft assembly but am super new to MIPS assembly, I've chose MARS assembler but things aren't going really good..

```
main:
li $s0, 0
li $s1, 0
li $s5, 100 


Loop: slti  $t0, $S0, 100
      beq  $S3, $zero, Fin
      add  $s1, $S1, $s0
      addi $S0, $s0, 1
      j Loop
```

There's no single line without errors.. but I really can't figure why.. The code is right or that is what I believe..

```
Error in /home/****/Desktop/Ex.asm line 9 column 18: "$S0": operand is of incorrect type
Error in /home/****/Desktop/Ex.asm line 10 column 12: "$S3": operand is of incorrect type
Error in /home/****/Desktop/Ex.asm line 11 column 17: "$S1": operand is of incorrect type
Error in /home/****/Desktop/Ex.asm line 12 column 12: "$S0": operand is of incorrect type
```

I tested this on another Windows machine.. and it worked.. :? using Debian here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lower case `s` characters.  Your assembler appears to not like the capital ones.

Comment: Wow.. well seems yeah.. :s